Errors running Psim in ubuntu after updating 24.04.01
I had downloaded Psim with Wine on Ubuntu 22.04, and it was working perfectly. Now I've upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.01, and I can no longer launch the application. It doesn't show any errors; it simply doesn't open. What can I do?
